# java regex to extract log from a log file

Tags: java, regex

i have a log file of 6MB with TRACE INFO DEBUG ERROR log level and i want to create a java regex to get ALL log with a specified log level.

I want to get log for level DEBUG then only debug type is extract.
Or log details may have multiple line details.

following is the log file details :

```
* DEBUG [2015/11/25 00:06:59] /usr/local/elsa/node/elsa.pl (184) main:: 22497 [undef]
Starting process_batch
* DEBUG [2015/11/25 00:06:59] /usr/local/elsa/node/elsa.pl (271) main::_process_batch 22497 [undef]
Offline processing:  and using tempfile /data/elsa/tmp/buffers/1448438819.71967
* ERROR [2015/11/25 00:06:59] /usr/local/elsa/node/elsa.pl (295) main::_process_batch 22497 [undef]
Unable to parse log line: .  Only parsed into:
$VAR1 = [];
* DEBUG [2015/11/25 00:06:59] /usr/local/elsa/node/elsa.pl (316) main::_process_batch 22497 [undef]
Finished job process_batch with 0 logs processed and 0 new programs
* DEBUG [2015/11/25 00:06:59] /usr/local/elsa/node/elsa.pl (318) main::_process_batch 22497 [undef]
file size for file /data/elsa/tmp/buffers/1448438819.71967 is 0
* TRACE [2015/11/25 00:06:59] /usr/local/elsa/node/elsa.pl (327) main::_process_batch 22497 [undef]
No logs recorded
* DEBUG [2015/11/25 00:06:59] /usr/local/elsa/node/elsa.pl (188) main:: 22497 [undef]
Processed 0 records
* INFO [2015/11/25 00:07:00] /usr/local/elsa/node/elsa.pl (206) main:: 22497 [undef]
Exiting after processing 0 records
* TRACE [2015/11/25 00:07:04] /usr/local/elsa/node/elsa.pl (135) main:: 22520 [undef]
Processing file __OPS__...
* DEBUG [2015/11/25 00:07:04] /usr/local/elsa/node/elsa.pl (271) main::_process_batch 22520 [undef]
Offline processing:  and using tempfile /data/elsa/tmp/buffers/ops_1448438824.46437
* TRACE [2015/11/25 00:07:04] /usr/local/elsa/node/elsa.pl (135) main:: 22526 [undef]
Processing file __IMPORT__...
* INFO [2015/11/25 00:07:04] /usr/local/elsa/node/Indexer.pm (332) Indexer::initial_validate_directory 22522 [undef]
Deleting stale ops log /data/elsa/tmp/buffers/ops_1448438824.46437
* DEBUG [2015/11/25 00:07:04] /usr/local/elsa/node/Indexer.pm (364) Indexer::initial_validate_directory 22522 [undef]
files: $VAR1 = [
          '/data/elsa/tmp/buffers/.',
          '/data/elsa/tmp/buffers/..'
        ];
* DEBUG [2015/11/25 00:07:04] /usr/local/elsa/node/Indexer.pm (366) Indexer::initial_validate_directory 22522 [undef]
considering file /data/elsa/tmp/buffers/.
* DEBUG [2015/11/25 00:07:04] /usr/local/elsa/node/Indexer.pm (366) Indexer::initial_validate_directory 22522 [undef]
considering file /data/elsa/tmp/buffers/..
* TRACE [2015/11/25 00:07:04] /usr/local/elsa/node/Indexer.pm (1782) Indexer::_get_lock 22522 [undef]
Locked directory
* DEBUG [2015/11/25 00:07:04] /usr/local/elsa/node/Indexer.pm (567) Indexer::_validate_directory 22522 [undef]
Wiping via index temp_1
* TRACE [2015/11/25 00:07:04] /usr/local/elsa/node/Indexer.pm (2195) Indexer::_sphinx_index 22522 [undef]
Starting Sphinx indexing for temp_1
* DEBUG [2015/11/25 00:07:04] /usr/local/elsa/node/Indexer.pm (2201) Indexer::_sphinx_index 22522 [undef]
output: Sphinx 2.1.9-id64-release (rel21-r4761)
Copyright (c) 2001-2014, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2014, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
```

and then i want to get log only with specified level ... 
and i use following code , buts its not work properly.

```
public class T {
    public static CharSequence fromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
        FileChannel channel = input.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer bbuf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, (int)channel.size());
        CharBuffer cbuf = Charset.forName("8859_1").newDecoder().decode(bbuf);
        input.close();
        return cbuf;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((DEBUG.*?)(([\n].*?)+)((TRACE)|(ERROR)|(INFO)))");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fromFile("d:/log.txt"));
            int count = 0;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String match = matcher.group();
                System.out.println("::: "+match.substring(0,match.lastIndexOf(" ")-1));
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("Total Matches : "+count);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I want all log with level DEBUG
there are some other log files cannot have '*' pattern

Please help 
Thanks in advancd

Comment: its just a request and i am try alot and continue working on it . and also code to do this task but its not using java regex and now i am want to use regex concept OK.

Comment: problem is that result not exactly return DEBUG level its also comes with other levels

Comment: Configuring your logger to write entries of DEBUG level into a separate file is not an option ? Besides that I don't see a reason why you need a regex: `DEBUG` should always be at the same position on each line

Comment: dear @Marged you do it before ? just tell me what you say using this line 'DEBUG should always be at the same position on each line'  So what ?

Comment: You want to extract just `DEBUG` part with  `INFO/ERROR/TRACE` word, or with whole `INFO/ERROR/TRACE` content?

Comment: i want to extract just DEBUG part from log file , some time DEBUG have multi line messages.  (60 - 70 lines).

Comment: like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/gW2cF4/1)?

Comment: Thanks @m.cekiera for your consideration , But now Last debug message is not picked by apply regex .  and word TRACE ERROR INFO are included and i dont want those words .

Comment: @SawaiSingh and what about [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/gW2cF4/2)?

Comment: @m.cekiera thanks , But regex also gives TRACE log details.

Comment: Why not just substring the line and check if it contains `DEBUG` at the n-th position ? Will be even faster than a regex.

Comment: dear @Marged sir , its not allowed to read log file line by line OK.

Comment: Can you give me the reason why it is not allowed to read the log file line by line ?!?

Comment: dear @Marged  just look the java code given below if its possible or allowed to read the file line by line then no problem. we solve it out already. And we are not on position to ask the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract only DEBUG lines, try with:

```
DEBUG[^*]*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gW2cF4/6)

you can chage a log information type by changing DEBUG on anything else. So the main part would be:

```
TYPE[^*]*
```

Comment: actually it was my mistake, it is not necessary at all, whats now?

Comment: but output string is not complete. its not contain '*' at starting position

Comment: just add it `\* DEBUG[^*]*`

Comment: ((\\bTRACE\\b.*?)(([\r\n].*?)+)((DEBUG)|(ERROR)|(INFO)|($$)))                     its from my side because some log file cannot contains '*'.

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks for your support @m.cekiera

Answer (score 0):

((\bTRACE\b.*?)(([\r\n].*?)+)((DEBUG)|(ERROR)|(INFO)|($$)))

and also use like . . .

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\bTRACE\\b.*?)(([\r\n].*?)+)((DEBUG)|(ERROR)|(INFO)|($$)))");

            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fromFile("d:/demo.txt"));
            int count = 0;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String match = matcher.group();
                System.out.println("::: "+match.substring(0,match.lastIndexOf(" ")-1));
                count++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

using java code we do this task like .  ( i am really struggle from last weekend).
so i post the solutions.

```
    private String logLevelDenied1;
    private String logLevelDenied2;
    private String logLevelDenied3;
    private String logLevelDenied4;


private List<String> readLogFile(String level , LogFilesEnum logFile , int count) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try{
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(getLogFileLocation(logFile));
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
            String tempString;
            int recordCount = 0;
            boolean flag = true;
            setDeniedVariables(level);
            if(logFile == LogFilesEnum.QUERY || logFile == LogFilesEnum.SEARCHD) {
                level = "";
            }
            List<String> logDetails = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            while (((tempString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) && (recordCount < count)) {
                if (tempString.contains(level)) {
                    flag = true;
                    recordCount++;
                    logDetails.add(tempString);
                    while (flag && recordCount<count) {
                        tempString = bufferedReader.readLine();
                        if (tempString.contains(logLevelDenied1) || tempString.contains(logLevelDenied2) || tempString.contains(logLevelDenied3) || tempString.contains(logLevelDenied4))
                            flag = false;
                        else {
                            if(tempString.contains(level))
                                recordCount++;
                            logDetails.add(tempString);
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
            return logDetails;
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally{
            if (fileInputStream != null)
                 fileInputStream.close();
            if (bufferedReader != null)
                 bufferedReader.close();
        }
    }





private void setDeniedVariables(String logLevel) {
        switch (logLevel.toUpperCase()) {
            case "ERROR":
                logLevelDenied1 = "TRACE";
                logLevelDenied2 = "DEBUG";
                logLevelDenied3 = "WARN";
                logLevelDenied4 = "INFO";
                break;
            case "TRACE":
                logLevelDenied1 = "ERROR";
                logLevelDenied2 = "DEBUG";
                logLevelDenied3 = "WARN";
                logLevelDenied4 = "INFO";   
                break;
            case "INFO":
                logLevelDenied1 = "TRACE";
                logLevelDenied2 = "DEBUG";
                logLevelDenied3 = "WARN";
                logLevelDenied4 = "ERROR";
                break;
            case "WARN":    
                logLevelDenied1 = "TRACE";
                logLevelDenied2 = "DEBUG";
                logLevelDenied3 = "ERROR";
                logLevelDenied4 = "INFO";
                break;
            case "DEBUG":   
                logLevelDenied1 = "TRACE";
                logLevelDenied2 = "ERROR";
                logLevelDenied3 = "WARN";
                logLevelDenied4 = "INFO";
                break;
            default :
                logLevelDenied1 = "--NONE--";
                logLevelDenied2 = "--NONE--";
                logLevelDenied3 = "--NONE--";
                logLevelDenied4 = "--NONE--";
        }
    }
```